# Anyone have some TAP or SNPP examples?

Tags: c#, c++, paging, tap

Does anyone know of a good resource with some examples of using the Telocator Alphanumeric Protocol (TAP) and/or the Simple Network Paging Protocol (SNPP) in either C++ or C#?

Thanks!

Comment: On a side note, did you happen to find any SNPP or WCTP implementations? I'm needing something for c# and just checking to see what you went with.

Comment: I implemented a very simple SNPP client in C#, but I've since moved on to another company, so I don't have access to it anymore. The protocol is extremely simple, though: http://www.snpp.info/ Unfortunately, I never investigated WCTP.

Comment: No problem, I thought I'd check anyways seeing that you're the only other person asking about paging protocols on SO other than myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TAP](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/pagers.html)

Not C++ but:

Perl [Net::SNPP module](http://www.xav.com/perl/site/lib/Net/SNPP.html)